# Edit CSS code dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm new in ASP.NET and i have a little problem . I have a master page which has a div and i want to edit the height of this div dynamically with code. I don't want to change the href to another css file  , i just want to edit this css file.

```
<div id="div" runat="server" ></div> 


#div
{
position:absolute;
background-color:red;
width:200px;
height:150px;
}
```

I tried this , but doesn't work :

```
      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div;

      div.Style.Add("height","200px");
```

Comment: where exactly do you try to set height attribute? (OnLoad?) How did you check that new value was not applied? (Dev tools, Firebug?)

Comment: I try to set height attribute in a  button press event. I run the site in browser and the div has same height (150px). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick...

If you're writing this code in the code-beind of the master page you can just write the following:

```
div.Attributes.Add("style", "position:absolute;background-color:red;height:200px;height:150px;");
```

Otherwise, if you're on a content page, you'd add this before the code above...

```
var div = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) Page.Master.FindControl("div");
```

Comment: You should also be able to just assign the class to the div using div.Attributes.Add("class", "nameOfDivClass");  This would be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Although Scottys answer is correct, a nicer way might be the following:

```
div.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height", "200px");
```

This will allow you to change individual css attributes.